# Creating a GUI that outputs month and days using array

Tags: arrays

I was tasked to make a simple program that when you enter a number it will show you the month and how many days there are in the month using arrays. Designing the GUI is done. I'm just confused on how to make the program come out with 2 outputs that will show a string and a int. I have 3 text fields. 1st will be the input where the user can put in 1 to 12 and when the button is pressed, the 2nd text field will show the month and the 3rd text field will show the date. I have already declared the input and the arrays for month and days. how do i connect the text field 1 to the 2 arrays? and how can I make the arrays come out of their respective text field? thank you for your help mates.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? What is the exact problem that you're facing? Do you get any error? What exactly have you tried out till now?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: Were using java. I cant make the program to get the input, match it with the month array and days array and print the result in the 2nd and 3rd textfield. all i have so far is the declaration of jtextfield1 get text, string for the 1st array and int for the 2nd array. from what I was told i need to connect the input to the 2 arrays and have them print out in their respective jtextfields.

Comment: this is what I have so far. but I dont know where to go or what command to use from here.

'int Month, result1, result2;'
        
Month = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
result1 = Month - 1;
result2 = Month - 1;
        
String [] MonthArray = {"January", "February"};
MonthArray = new String [12];
MonthArray [0] = "January";
MonthArray [1] = "February";
//goes till december
jTextField2.setText(String.valueOf(MonthArray));
        
int [] DaysArray;
DaysArray = new int [12];
DaysArray [0] = 31;
//(goes till day 11)
jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(DaysArray));
       
help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to decide when to call the function. You can add a button or handler to detect changes on first text field. Create a function to process data.

Then you need to check input in this function. You need to be sure that input is an integer number in correct interval, not a string, fractional or negative number.

After checks, you should use operation to access element by index and put result of this operations to your output fields.